# Memcache::close PHP

Tags: php, memcached

Обязательно ли закрывать соединение Memcache? И на что повлияет то что он не будет закрыт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В memcached на сколько очень много времени тратится на соединение именно, поэтому весь смыл его использования в том, что оно постоянно открытым держится.

Применять кэширование стоит только на высоконагруженных ресурсах. Что касается больших проектов, лучше сразу написать больше строк кода, чем потом делать это в попыхах, с мыслью о том, что ваш сервис лежит. Также не стоит забывать о расходовании памяти! Учтите, что положив 300 мегабайт в кэш, вы отняли у себя 300 мегабайт ОЗУ...

Comment: @marrk2, Зачем мне это если я и так это давно видел http://habrahabr.ru/post/108274/ по вопросу можете что то ответить конкретно?